# Unable to resolve vulnerability dependency in POM file for webdrivermanager

Tags: maven, security, dependencies, webdriver, pom.xml

Error
Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3 CVE-2022-42003 7.5 Deserialization of Untrusted Data vulnerability with High severity found Cxced0c06c-935c 5.9 Uncontrolled Resource Consumption vulnerability with Medium severity found CVE-2022-42004 7.5 Deserialization of Untrusted Data vulnerability with High severity found CVE-2021-46877 7.5 Uncontrolled Resource Consumption vulnerability with High severity found CVE-2020-25649 7.5 Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference vulnerability with High severity found CVE-2020-36518 7.5 Out-of-bounds Write vulnerability with High severity found CVE-2021-20190 8.1 Deserialization of Untrusted Data vulnerability with High severity found  Results powered by Checkmarx(c)

I am adding webdriver dependency in POM file for selenium automation but no matetr which version i give still it gives me vulenrability error so unable to resolve it, so maven not resolving error so run button in intellij is disabled

Comment: You are using an old version of jackson.. that's the reason for those hints... you have to update your dependencies to newer versions of jackson...?